# Classic asp not publicly available

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp-classic

I need to call a classic asp page from .net, because I need the functionality of the classic asp page within my .net app.

The only way I know how to do that at the moment is like this :

```cs
MeetingCentres.Services.ClassicWhyGo.file_get_contents("http://someurl.asp?inputValue=£$%$£"%$£"%$£%)

    public static string file_get_contents(string fileName)
    {
        string sContents = string.Empty;
        if (fileName.ToLower().IndexOf("http:") > -1)
        { // URL 
            System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
            byte[] response = wc.DownloadData(fileName);
            sContents = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response);
        }
        else
        {
            // Regular Filename 
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
            sContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }
        return sContents;
    }
```

...but this means that the classic asp page is accessed over http and hence publicly available.

How ever I need to protect this page somehow as sensitive information is returned.

I would prefer to not have this asp page publicly available.

In IIS there doesn't seem to be the ability to make the page available only above the website root, as far as I know?

Otherwise if it must be public was thinking that I may be able to check the ip address of the calling.net app and make sure that it is on the same server.

Is there a better way to do this? or would the above be safe..?

Comment: Side note: This statement "accessed over http and hence publicly available" is your personal opinion - being accessible over HTTP have nothing to do with being publicly available. I.e. my machine have ASP.Net sample site available over HTTP on http://localhost - can you get to it? External availability depends on your network configuration and not directly related to http protocol.

Comment: I'm talking about my current set up, that I'm looking for a solution to. Thanks for your clarification

Comment: You are *thinking* about your current setup, there is no information on how your sites/public access setup in the post. Possibly you can server other site from non default port and block it on firewall from being accessible outside of the box... Look at your setup and update post so it is clear what your current setup is you want to prevent (what exactly "publicly accessible" means in your case).

Comment: Can you run the Classic ASP as a separate website on a different port that is protected from external access via firewall?

Comment: @John yes, this is what I have done now

Answer (score 2):

You are able to modify the .asp page?

Do some tests like:

- Check if the IP address are the same:

  ```vbs
  <%
      if Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR") = "127.0.0.1" then
          'Do your stuff
      end if
  %>
  ```
- Create a Cookie, store a encoded key and test it and only show the data if the value equals the key.

  ```vbs
  <%
      Response.Cookies("key")=encodedKey
  %>
  ```
- Test the cookie

  ```vbs
  <%
      if Decode(Response.Cookies("key")) = decodedKey then
          'Do your stuff
      end if
  %>
  ```

This are just simples ideas.

Comment: Note that REMOTE_ADDR can be forged.